# On the paradox that $n$-coskeletal simplicial sets model all homotopy types

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Please help me resolve the following paradox:

> > **False claim:** Let $X$ be an $n$-coskeletal, $n$-connected simplicial set. Then $X$ is weakly contractible.

Actually, I suppose the claim is true when $n=0$; but it is false for $n\geq 1$: nerves of posets realize all homotopy types, and these are 1-coskeletal.

**Paradoxical "Proof" of false claim:** Fix $m > n$. To show that $\pi_m(X) = 0$, consider a map $f: Sd^k \partial \Delta^{m+1} \to X$; we want to show that for some $l$, $Sd^{k+l} \partial \Delta^{m+1} \to Sd^{k} \partial \Delta^{m+1} \xrightarrow f X$ extends along $Sd^{k+l} \partial \Delta^{m+1} \to Sd^{k+l} \Delta^{m+1}$. 
Here $Sd$ is barycentric subdivision. Since $X$ is $n$-coskeletal, it suffices to show this after passing to $n$-skeleta. But then this problem can be solved because $X$ is $n$-connected, so that (after subdivision) lifts exist along any map between $n$-skeletal simplicial sets.

**Resolution:** The problem with the "proof" is that subdivision fails to commute with taking skeleta.

**Paradoxical salvaged "proof":** One can still try to build an extension of $f$ as follows. First, find an extension along $Sd^{l_1} sk_n Sd^k \partial \Delta^{m+1} \to Sd^{l_1} sk_n Sd^k \Delta^{m+1}$. To turn this into an extension along $sk_n Sd^{k+l_1} \partial \Delta^{m+1} \to sk_n Sd^{k+l_1} \Delta^{m+1}$ involves another lifting problem along a map between $n$-skeletal simplicial sets, so it can be solved after applying $Sd^{l_2}$. Continue in this manner, and you eventually construct an extension of $f$ along $Sd^\infty \partial \Delta^{m+1} \to Sd^\infty \Delta^{m+1}$. This shows that the homotopy group represented by $f$ is trivial.

**Attempted resolution:**
The process doesn't converge at a finite stage. The loophole must be that $Sd^\infty \partial \Delta^{m+1}$ doesn't have the homotopy type of $\partial \Delta^{m+1}$.

**Questions:**

1. Is the map $\partial \Delta^{m+1} \to Sd^\infty \partial \Delta^{m+1} := \varinjlim_l Sd^l \partial \Delta^{m+1}$ a weak homotopy equivalence?
2. If so, then how does one actually resolve the revived paradox?
3. Even if not, is there a better way to formulate the resolution of the revived paradox? It feels as though a loophole was exploited.
4. I think I'm starting to see why by the naure of "subdivision", no such operator is going to commute with taking skeleta. But if someone has a nice way to formulate why this is so, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Is your claim really false? The $n$-coskeleton is a model for the $(n-1)$-truncation of the homotopy type (see here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243164/what-is-the-intuitive-meaning-of-the-coskeleton-of-a-simplicial-set). So an $n$-connected $n$-coskeletal simplicial set will have all homotopy groups zero, right?

Comment: Wait, scratch that - the statement about truncation is only true for Kan complexes...

Comment: I don't understand the map in (1.). What is the map $K\to Sd K$ that you're using? (the map I know goes the other way...)

Comment: @SamGunningham Exactly :)

Comment: @DenisNardin You're right, that doesn't make any sense. So the whole "salvaged paradox" thing falls apart because there isn't really a colimit to be approaching -- $Sd^\infty$ doesn't exist as a colimit (though it does as a limit, it's hard to see how to map out of this). Nevertheless, I'm having trouble dispelling the sense that there should be an argument to be had somewhere in this neighborhood. Is there something to say about hashing out homotopy groups of coskeletal simplicial sets in terms of lifting properties against skeletal things...

Comment: The nerve of a poset is a Kan complex iff it is trivial. If you take a fibrant replacement of it (i.e. you consider it as an object of the $\infty$-cosmos of $\infty$-groupoids), so that you can correctly define its homotopy groups, this will not be 1-connected in general.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the map in (1.) actually goes the other way around. Nevertheless, $l\colon\text{Sd}^{\infty}X\to X$ is a weak equivalence. Indeed, let $K$ be any Kan complex, $l$ induces a bijection between the sets of homotopy classes of maps 
\begin{equation*}
l^*\colon [X,K]\to [\text{Sd}^{\infty}X,K]\simeq [X,\text{Ex}^{\infty}K]\simeq [X,K]
\end{equation*} 
Where the first isomorphism comes from the fact that the adjunction $(\text{Sd},\text{Ex})$ is simplicial.

Now, I think the paradox in your proof is in the second sentence. I don't see why one should expect an extension along $\text{Sd}^l\text{sk}_n\text{Sd}^k\partial\Delta^{m+1}\to \text{Sd}^l\text{sk}_n\text{Sd}^k\Delta^{m+1}$ to exist (Unless this is somehow a consequence of the coskeletal condition). 
Let me explain why I don't think such an extension would exist in general.

We are trying to find a lift in the following diagram, for some $l$
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\text{Sd}^l\text{sk}_n\text{Sd}^k\partial\Delta^{m+1}@>f_{|\text{sk}_n}\circ \text{l.v.}>>X\\
@VVV\\
\text{Sd}^l\text{sk}_n\text{Sd}^k\Delta^{m+1}
\end{CD}
$$
where $\text{l.v.}$ is the last vertex map.
This is equivalent to finding a lift in the following diagram
$$\begin{CD}
\text{sk}_n\text{Sd}^k\partial\Delta^{m+1}@>j_X\circ f_{|\text{sk}_n}>>\text{Ex}^{\infty}X\\
@VVV\\
\text{sk}_n\text{Sd}^k\Delta^{m+1}
\end{CD}
$$
where $j_X\colon X\to \text{Ex}^{\infty}X$ is the usual inclusion.
But $\text{sk}_n\text{Sd}^k\partial\Delta^{m+1}\to\text{sk}_n\text{Sd}^k\Delta^{m+1}$ is not a weak-equivalence if $k\geq 1$, and so we have no reason to expect that such a lift exists.

To see why this map is not a weak equivalence, consider the fact that part of the $n$-skeleton of $\text{Sd}\Delta^{m+1}$ is contained in the "interior" of $\Delta^{m+1}$. 
This also gives you an example of (4), since if we reverse the order of subdivision and truncation, we get an isomorphism $\text{Sd}^k \text{sk}_n\partial\Delta^{m+1}\simeq \text{Sd}^k \text{sk}_n\Delta^{m+1}$.

Comment: Thanks, Sylvain! I think I was thinking that $sk_n Sd^k \partial \Delta^{m+1}$ was a retract of $sk_n Sd^k \Delta^{m+1}$, just not a deformation retract. This is true after taking geometric realization, but on reflection it's simply not true before geometric realization. It's kind of fun to draw out $sk_1 Sd^2 \Delta^2$ an think about why this is so. The obstruction has a sort of "metric" feel.

Comment: However, I believe it _is_ the case that these lifts exist! To see this, use the fact that $Ex^\infty X$ is a retract of $Sing |X|$, so we may replace $Ex^\infty X$ with $Sing |X|$ in the lifting problem. Then by adjunction, it suffices to observe that $|sk_n Sd^k \partial \Delta^{m+1}| \to |sk_n Sd^k \Delta^{m+1}|$ has a retraction.

Comment: I did not realize it was enough to have a retract, nor that $|sk_nSd^k∂Δ^{m+1}|→|sknSd^kΔ^{m+1}|$ actually admited one, thank you for pointing it out. I am not sure to see why $ \text{Ex}^{\infty}$ should be a retract of $\text{Sing}(|X|)$. The fact that they are homotopically equivalent is straightforward, but I don't think this implies that one is the retract of the other. I do agree that if it is true, this implies the existence of a lift.

Comment: And for the obstruction to have a retract, I think that $\text{sk}_1\text{Sd}^1\Delta^2$ already gives a counter example, since the image of the "middle" vertex would have to be connected to every other vertices in $\text{sk}_1\text{Sd}^1\partial\Delta^2$

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. I still don't think $\text{Ex}^{\infty}X$ is a retract of $\text{Sing}|X|$, but this is not needed to show the existence of a lift. Take any weak equivalence $\text{Ex}^{\infty}X\to \text{Sing}|X|$ and factor it through some space $Z$ as a trivial cofibration followed by a trivial fibration. Now $Z$ is a retract of $\text{Ex}^{\infty}X$ and $Z\to \text{Sing}|X|$ is a trivial fibration. This should provide the existence of a lift using your previous remarks.

Comment: We have canonical acyclic cofibrations $X \to Ex^\infty X$ and $X \to Sing |X|$, and my thought was that there was a canonical factorization $Ex^\infty X \to Sing |X|$ which was injective, and a homotopy equivalence by 2/3. Then because $Ex^\infty X$ is fibrant, this map would have a retract. But now I'm not so sure there is such an injective factoriztion. Of course, your argument seems to be actually correct!